# "Functions that are created at run time"

Tags: python, function, python-decorators

I learned from [here](https://medium.com/@taohidulii/functions-as-first-class-object-in-python-a1b8e2f91acb) that one of the characteristics of a first class object is that it can be created at run time.

It is not clear for me when a function is actually created at a run time. Can one tell me how I can identify a function that is created at run time and a function that it not created at run time? All the functions in python are created at run time?

Comment: Ask the [author](https://medium.com/@taohidulii)

Comment: An object is a collection of data and associated functions. The data is created at runtime, but the functions generally are not. In most cases the functions that make up a class definition are grouped in advance, but it is also possible to select specific functions as members of the object at runtime. The selection is runtime, but all the functions exist in advance in traditional languages.

Comment: To learn more about functions created at run time, read about [lambda functions](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/) and examine the [functools module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html).

Comment: But even lambda functions are not written at runtime, they are just created without a name.

Comment: I guess the one case of truly dynamic functions is such as `eval` in bash, where you could construct a string at runtime and have that string be executed, but in the land of bash, everything is evaluated as a string at runtime, so even then the distinction is fuzzy. In the history of computing we have the concept of `self modifying code`, which is probably as close as you will get to true dynamic programming.

Answer (score 1):

that post isn't amazing...  everything in Python is "created at runtime" you'd need to compare to a compiled language (e.g. C) to find a difference between compile time and run time.  you could also compare to languages like PHP (which you seem to have used) where you have to [call magic methods like `call_user_func`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) and pass a string instead of just passing a function object around.  I don't know PHP very well, but it would seem to struggle with idioms like:

```
def foo(a):
  def bar(b):
    return a * b
  return bar

baz = foo(3)
print(baz(5))
```

where `baz` is a closure that "bound" `a` to the value `3`, i.e. keeping a reference to it around so it can be used later.  I think you'd need to create a class and object that bundles this functionality up in PHP

I feel like a link to a talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns might help understand better how names and values work in Python.  a more advanced tool would be the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) which can be good for understanding how things like this work